# VB6 Word.Application reference results in "Library not registered" error message

Tags: dll, reference, vb6, ms-office, office-interop

I know there are many questions like this out there, but none of the answers resolve my issues.

Opening a word application in a VB6 project works in most cases (almost all), but there is one particular computer that keeps nagging about the reference.

These are some of the steps I did in an attempt to solve it:

1. Remove DLL reference from project. Remove Registry folder (forcing
   word to reregister itself)
2. Renoved all Office folders (office11,
   office12, office13, ...) resulting in only the folder office14
   (office 2010) left.
3. Registering the DLL manually using REGSVR32 (full
   paths specified in elevated command prompt.
4. Add DLL reference to project.
5. Tried Word.Application, GetObject and CreateObject methods

The error message always states that the DLL is not registered.

The computer did have office 2007 installed before and still has some leftovers installed like projects (or something like that).

@Hans Thank you for the quick response.
To clarify the error message. It literally states: "Library or DLL not registered".
By removing the office folders from C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Office\ I forced office to run the repair setup. Assuming because the registry entries and the DLL's were gone, the problem would fix itself. I guess not.

Comment: You cannot get Office installed properly by trying to register it by hand.  Not quoting the *exact* error message doesn't help us help you.  Run the Office installer, it isn't very clear if will be capable of repairing the damage.

Comment: When removing the word folders and opening word from start, the repair setup is triggered, just to clarify ;)